# Axios PUT request fails with error status code 500: Internal Server error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, react-redux

I am new to Reactjs and I am trying a simple CRUD operation using react redux node mongodb. when I try to update an employee record I receive Internal server error 500 . ie **('Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" (type string) at path "_id" for model "employee"'}).**  Here's part of my server code using expressjs

```
 router.put('/employees/:id', async (request, response) => {
    let employeeId = request.params.id;
    let updatedEmployee = {
        name: request.body.name,
        age: request.body.age,
        designation: request.body.designation,
        phone: request.body.phone
    }
    try {
        let employee = await Employee.findById(employeeId);
        if (!employee) {
            return response.status(401).json({
                msg: 'Employee Doesnot Exist'
            })
        }
        employee = await Employee.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeId, {
            $set: updatedEmployee
        }, { new: true })
        response.status(200).json({
            result: "Employee updated successfully",
            employee: employee
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        response.status(500).json({
            error: error.message
        })
    }
})
```

And I dispatched action using redux in clientside

```
export const updateEmployeeDetails = (selectedEmployee, employeeId, navigate) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: UPDATE_EMP_REQUEST })
            let dataURL = `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/employees/${employeeId}`
            let response = await Axios.put(dataURL, selectedEmployee)
            dispatch({ type: UPDATE_EMP_SUCCESS, payload: response.data })
            navigate.push('/employees')
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error(error.response.data)
            dispatch({ type: UPDATE_EMP_FAILURE, payload: error })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Code:500 case from server, check your server error by user try and catch to know what's make error 500

Comment: @JawadFadel Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" (type string) at path "_id" for model "employee"'}

Comment: sure if you sending the data as json

Comment: @JawadFadel yes everything works fine like get,create,delete except update. The error in the server terminal is BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters

Comment: check your  schema type is all correct or not

Comment: @JawadFadel Here is the repo link https://github.com/sara02selvaraj/emp_CRUD. I have sent the same id format in the URL to 'get a single employee detail ' , it works fine. But wher it went wrong in updating a employee detail.